# How can I merge two LINQ queries into one query?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have the following SQL query:

```
select 
    [Event2].EventType AS 'Event type', 
    SUM (1)            AS 'Number of events', 
    AVG(DATEDIFF(Second, [Event1].CreationDate, [Event2].CreationDate)) AS 'Time'
from [Event] as [Event1]
join [Event] as [Event2] on [Event1].Id = [Event2].ParentId
group by [Event2].EventTypeId;
```

for which I found two LINQ queries.

```
// This query brings the event types and the differences between the events.
var rows = from event1 in _eventRepository.AsQueryable()
           join event2 in _eventRepository.AsQueryable() on event1.Id equals event2.ParentId
           select new 
           {
               EventId = event2.EventId, 
               TimeInSeconds = DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(event1.CreationDate, event2.CreationDate) 
           };

// This query groups the rows before by Event type.
var groups = (from item in rows  
              group item by item.EventTypeId into g
              select new EventModel
              {
                  EventTypeId = g.Key,
                  NumberOfEvents = g.Sum(x => 1),
                  Time = (int) g.Average(x => x.TimeInSeconds)
              }).ToList();
```

I have to merge this queries into a single one. 
The result must contain three elements: `Event Type`, `The number of events`, `The Average` of the time elapsed between the creation date of first event and the creation date of the second event.

Comment: Why do you have to merge it into a single one?

Comment: Because the Event table can contain a lot of rows at some time and there is too many data brought into memory.

Comment: @PianoSong - data isn't brought back to memory until the `ToList()`

Comment: What makes you think the first query brings anything into memory @PianoSong ? I would suggest giving a trial of https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof a go. You may be surprised to see what lines are actually causing SQL to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the grouping statement to the first query (instead of the select):

```
var result = (from event1 in _eventRepository
              join event2 in _eventRepository on event1.Id equals event2.ParentId

              group new {
                EventId =  event2.EventId,
                TimeInSeconds = DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(event1.CreationDate, event2.CreationDate)
              }
              by event2.EventTypeId into g

              select new EventModel {
                EventTypeId = g.Key,
                NumberOfEvents = g.Count(),
                Time = (int) g.Average(x => x.TimeInSeconds)
              }).ToList();
```

You can also not specify the fields in the grouping but just in the select statement but left it as that is the original